# Regular expression on separate function of Tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

I need separate two columns with tidyr.

The column have text like: `I am Sam`. I mean the text always have only two white spaces, and the text can have all other symbols: `[a-z][0-9][!\ºª, etc...]`.

The problem is I need split it in two columns: Column one `I am`, and column two: `Sam`.

I can't find a regular expression two separate with the second blank space.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr`.  We match one or more characters and place it in a capture group (`(.*)`) followed by one or more space (`\\s+`) and another capture group that contains only non-white space characters (`\\S+`) to separate the original column into two columns.

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, Col1, into = c("Col1", "Col2"), "(.*)\\s+(\\S+)")
#   Col1 Col2
#1  I am  Sam
#2 He is  Sam
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("I am Sam", "He is Sam"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Great answer, but you should explain what the regex is doing so OP can understand.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, given:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(txt = "I am Sam")
```

you can use

```
separate(, txt, c("a", "b"), sep="(?<=\\s\\S{1,100})\\s") 
#      a   b
# 1 I am Sam
```

with `separate` using `stringi::stri_split_regex` (ICU engine), or

```
separate(df, txt, c("a", "b"), sep="^.*?\\s(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\s", perl=TRUE)
```

with the older (?) `separate` using `base:strsplit` (Perl engine). See also

```
strsplit("I am Sam", "^.*?\\s(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\s", perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "I am" "Sam"
```

But it might be a bit "esoterique"...