# R - Regex to separate string based on first dot?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyr

I have a column which is filled with strings containing multiple dots. I want to split this column into two containing the two substrings before and after the first dot.

I.e.

```
comb          num
UWEA.n.49.sp   3
KYFZ.n.89.kr   5
     ...
```

Into

```
 a         b       num
UWEA    n.49.sp     3
KYFZ    n.89.kr     5
     ...
```

I'm using the `separate` function from `tidyr` but cannot get the regexp correct. I'm trying to use the regex style from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240306/regular-expression-on-separate-function-of-tidyr):

```
foo %>%
    separate(comb, into=c('a', 'b'),
             sep="([^.]+)\\.(.*)")
```

So that column `a` should be determined by the first capture group `([^.]+)` containing at least one non-dot characters, then the first dot, then the second capture group `(.*)` just matches whatever remains after.

However this doesn't seem to match anything:

```
a   b   num
         3
         5
```

Here's my dummy dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
foo <- data.frame(comb=replicate(10, 
                                 paste(paste(sample(LETTERS, 4), collapse=''),
                                       sample(c('p', 'n'), 1), 
                                       sample(1:100, 1), 
                                       paste(sample(letters, 2), collapse=''), 
                                       sep='.')
                                 ),
                  num = sample(1:10, 10, replace=T))
```

Comment: Why use a regex when there's a built-in function to split strings? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that function still requires regex for the `split` argument, I'd then have to manually set the result to two different columns. Using tidyr's `separate` function is simpler.

Comment: `foo %>% separate(comb, into = c("a","b"), sep = "(?<=[A-Z])\\.(?=[a-z]+)")`.

Comment: That doesn't work @RichScriven, column a is the full string and b is <NA>. Possibly because that example requires Perl like regex which `separate` doesn't allow. 

@Abdou that works! If you write it up as an answer with some explanation of what the `?<=` and `?=` does I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think @aosmith's answer is great and definitely less clunky than a `regex` solution involving lookarounds. But since you're intent on using `regex`, here it is:

```
foo %>% 
    separate(comb, 
             into = c("a","b"), 
             sep = "(?<=[A-Z])\\.(?=[a-z]+)")
```

The trick here is the regex itself. It uses what is known as [`lookaround`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). Basically, you are looking for a dot (`.`) that's placed between an uppercase letter and a lowercase letter (i.e. `UWEA.n`) for the `sep` parameter. It means: `match a dot preceded by a capital letter and followed by a lowercase letter`.

This allows the `separate` function to split the `comb` column on the dots that are between `A` and `n` or between `Z` and `n`, in your case.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

This is a case where you can take advantage of the `extra = "merge"` option in `separate`.  Because `separate` separates on symbols by default, you don't have to define the separator.  If you wanted to, you could use `"\\."`

```
foo %>%
    separate(comb, into=c('a', 'b'), extra = "merge")

      a       b num
1  NPTE p.10.ku   4
2  YAIU p.54.lw   4
3  CHUR n.51.kx   6
4  EPGX n.14.lg   3
5  POBJ n.11.ja   5
6  LEWI n.72.un   7
7  WLAP n.20.ve  10
8  XZUY p.75.cf   6
9  ZSNJ  p.4.aj   3
10 ABKR n.69.ua   3
```

`extra = "merge"` takes all the extra pieces beyond the columns you defined and merges them into the last column.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say in the question I wanted a full regex answer as I'd like to improve my skills. I'd got it working this way but was frustrated at my inability to use what seemed to me to be a basic regex format.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option .  Replace the first `.` with `,` in the 'comb' column, read with `read.csv` to create two columns based on the delimiter `,` and `cbind` with the other columns of 'foo'

```
cbind(read.csv(text=sub("\\.", ",", foo$comb), 
          col.names = c('a', 'b'), header=FALSE), foo[-1])
#      a       b num
#1  GJMU n.83.cu   3
#2  IVMD p.85.ny   9
#3  HLQB p.94.rd   8
#4  WIJY n.92.sz   4
#5  QXCM n.38.lf   8
#6  UBNC n.82.js   5
#7  EPLZ n.56.kl   3
#8  YRBA  n.6.ny   8
#9  HQMR p.54.pn  10
#10 LBPO p.98.tv   7
```

---

Or another option is with `extract` from `tidyr` where we match one or more character that are not a `.`, place it in a capture group (`([^.]+)`), followed by a dot (`\\.`) followed by other characters in the second capture group (`(.*)`).  The captured group characters return as two columns replacing the original 'comb' column.

```
library(tidyr)
extract(foo, comb, into = c("a", "b"), "([^.]+)\\.(.*)")
#      a       b num
#1  GJMU n.83.cu   3
#2  IVMD p.85.ny   9
#3  HLQB p.94.rd   8
#4  WIJY n.92.sz   4
#5  QXCM n.38.lf   8
#6  UBNC n.82.js   5
#7  EPLZ n.56.kl   3
#8  YRBA  n.6.ny   8
#9  HQMR p.54.pn  10
#10 LBPO p.98.tv   7
```

NOTE: There was no `set.seed` in the OP's post